# how to test if a variable has numbers javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I could test if a variable has numbers
I tried with two codes but none worked.

```
var adressevalidation = document.getElementById("adresse").value;
console.log(adressevalidation);

//test de l'adresse il doit y avoir un numero valable pour tous les pays
if (!preg_match('#[\d ]#', (adressevalidation))) {
  document.getElementById("myadresse").innerHTML = "pas de numero";
  document.getElementById("adresse").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

if (!adressevalidation.match(/^([a-zA-Z ]+)$/)) {
  document.getElementById("myadresse").innerHTML = "pas de numero";
  document.getElementById("adresse").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple function for that

```js
var adressevalidation = document.getElementById("adresse").value;


function containsNumbers(str) {
  return /\d/.test(str);
}

console.log(containsNumbers(adressevalidation))
```

```html
<input type="text" id="adresse" value="sfg5rgb6hd">
```